# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser почему находит только одно?

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom

Есть код

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://m.vk.com/' . $link . '');
    $links = array();
    foreach($html->find('source[type="video/mp4"]') as $a) {
     $links[] = $a->src;
    }

    print_r($links);
```

На странице есть несколько ссылок

```
<source src="ссылка/p3/f0cba78674f7.720.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="ссылка/p11/f0cba78674f7.480.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="ссылка/p18/f0cba78674f7.360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="ссылка/p14/f0cba78674f7.240.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

Но находит только одну:

```
<source src="ссылка/p14/f0cba78674f7.240.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не воспроизводится http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pgzn-b8dg

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, замени на $html = str_get_html('https://m.vk.com/video-56263398_456255821');

Comment: вам надо сюда  https://habrahabr.ru/post/168343/